# How to hide Date Today in search engines With HTML TAGS?

Tags: html, seo

We may want show Date Today or Other things in our site on top of our website, **But this is not SEO**

We can bring the element at the bottom of the page and use this code for bring up:

```
position: absolute;
```

but this is not favorable.

My question is : Can we use tags: `<small>` or `<i>`

or `<samp>` (in HTML5) or other tags?
**no JavaScript, only HTML Tags**

Comment: No Java? Do you mean no JavaScript? Because the two are _very_ different beasts. And how is showing the date not SEO friendly?

Comment: Yes mean JavaScript, because must call a php function through java

Comment: Make sure not to confuse the two. JavaScript is definitely not Java. Calling it Java can be very confusing. Also, I still don't know why this isn't SEO friendly? What about it is not good for SEO?

Comment: oops I meaning JavaScript; search engines see this: 1.title or logo 2.menu 3. (this day 16 Feb 2012) 4. post title 5. content and ... you can see that this element (3) has added a line to view search engines. it's true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason having a date should not be SEO friendly *unless you are using it in a way that isn't*. The date will just be treated as content and will be parsed just like all of the other page text.

If you want to talk about what is best *semantically*, than that is a different story. You can use the HTML 5 [`<time>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-time-element-0), though if you do the date must be in a [*machine readable*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#concept-time-date) format.

Comment: This is the best idea. What if the **search box**?

Comment: A tag which say to search engine this part is not important.

Comment: Search engines don't really care what elements you think are most important, it just parses the page and does what it thinks is best. You can tell search engines to ignore pages, but not really content on the page. If you use proper semantics, it will have a better chance of knowing what is important.